# Want tool to obtain linear temporal logic spec from UML 2.0 sequence diagram

Tags: uml, logic, sequence-diagram, formal-methods, formal-verification

i am working on checking model consistency of software. to do this i need to write linear temporal logic for UML 2.0 sequence diagram. if any body have any other tool for the same please response as soon as possible. I will be very obliged to you.
i have found charmy tool have plugin for the same. Does anybody have source code for charmy tool(CHecking ARchitectural Model consistencY). It is not available on their website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many tools for model transformation and model checking when it comes to UML. Can you please give some reference to that "linear temporal logic"? I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Basically it is used to prove the safety and liveness property of a system. Here i am giving two link
1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic
2. http://www.di.univaq.it/pellicci/download.php?fileID=26

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715239/does-anybody-have-any-tool-to-generate-linear-temporal-logic-or-ctl-from-sequence

Comment: @Charles Stewart: That question does not exist (any more?).

Comment: @Gumbo: was it merged?  I tested the link when I posted the comment.

Comment: @Charles Stewart: That link is broken now for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence diagram model is for me unusable.

I mean that you can have a sequence diagram but the underlying model is really messy.
The sequence diagram is the only UML diagram which model is not really reusable.
Sorry for this post but I think that sequence diagram should remain graphical because the metamodel has not been well developped in the UML specification and it is too late to change it !!

Comment: Maybe it is not too late: http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/224701702;jsessionid=OWQYMR1NPFHN1QE1GHRSKHWATMY32JVN

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. According to [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram), a sequence diagram does not have any loops, so the corresponding LTL formula would not contain any diamonds or boxes etc, it would just be a sequence of atomic events, no?

Could you please provide an example sequence diagram and corresponding LTL formula?

Comment: You've misread. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html indicates that alternation and looping are possible.

Comment: Also, even with simple code there would still be a need for a good sprinkling of `◇` symbols; you can not count on the events from a sequence diagram happening immediately, so "eventually" is a useful modal operator. (God, I'm starting to remember some of this stuff…)